# CentOS 7.9.2009 server needs iptables flushed after each restart

Tags: iptables, centos7

Have a VPS running Centos 7.9, mainly used for Plesk webhosting.

Recently when we restart the server, all ports except for SSH (port 58431) are blocked. We have to SSH into the VPS and use `iptables --flush` to allow the websites to work, before stopping again on the next restart (usually after a couple of days).

`iptables --list` outputs the below and I have no idea where to even start with this. Can anyone spot the rule that is causing this, and possibly what might be putting it there?

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 4320 packets, 247K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 4322  247K PREROUTING_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 4322  247K PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 4322  247K PREROUTING_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 465K packets, 28M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 465K   28M POSTROUTING_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 465K   28M POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 465K   28M POSTROUTING_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 465K packets, 28M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 465K   28M OUTPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 4011  258K POST_public  all  --  *      venet0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
 461K   28M POST_public  all  --  *      +       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POST_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 465K   28M POST_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 465K   28M POST_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 465K   28M POST_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain POST_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POST_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POST_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain PREROUTING_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 4320  247K PRE_public  all  --  venet0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
    1    52 PRE_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain PREROUTING_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain PRE_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 4321  247K PRE_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 4321  247K PRE_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 4321  247K PRE_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain PRE_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain PRE_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain PRE_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: That output is so mangled I can't even make any sense of it. Please delete it, paste it again, and use _only_ the code `{}` formatting tool to format it.

Comment: BTW you should also use the `-n` and `-v` options when listing `iptables`.

Comment: Why not drop it and use firewalld ? It's a lot easier.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sorry, I somehow put the whole thing into a quote. It's still mangled though.

Comment: @Overmind Thought they were the same thing. I'll look into this now. Thanks.

Comment: @user2924019 `iptables -vnL` and `iptables -t nat -vnL` can provide much readable output.

Comment: @Adil Perfect. I've updated the paste in the question. Thanks.

Comment: It is interesting. There were some DROP rules in your previous snippet. There was a rule for 58431 in your previous snippet. However, those rules are disappeared in your current snippet.

Comment: Not sure why. The webserver just blocked access again and so I had to flush it - this time without a restart. We use fail2ban but that's never worked correctly.

Comment: Where is the rest of it? Please also include the output of `iptables -vnL` as was already requested.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Oh that was completely empty of any rules. I believe fail2ban was causing this and have now removed. I'll update once we know for sure.